# Looking for the census blocks that make up the most recent U.S. Congressional Districts

Tags: data, united-states, census, boundaries

I am hoping someone can help me solve this or point me in a direction. I need to know what census blocks make up the most recent Congressional Districts (115th). I have found a file that the US Census Bureau has which is the census blocks as they relate to older congressional districts (2013 I think), but not the most recent ones. The closest I can get is census tracts inside of congressional districts and I can work down from there. My understanding is that tracts can be cut by a congressional district ([Which census geography boundaries do congressional districts preserve?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55239/which-census-geography-boundaries-do-congressional-districts-preserve)), and I am not sure how to solve that.

I have tried an intersect, but the boundaries do not seem to work out quite correctly and I get some weird things included/excluded. A geoid relationship based text file would be ideal.

Comment: If this is open data then the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange may be more suitable for researching/asking your question

Comment: Thank you PolyGeo. I actually found a post with what I was looking for. If anyone else runs into this, see here: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6142/where-is-the-block-assignment-file-linking-2010-census-data-with-113th-congressi. Should I delete this or leave it up? I did not realize it was a duplicate from another SE community.

Comment: I think it would be useful for you to give a brief self-answer giving the Open Data SE link and summarizing how it helped answer your question. That is something that I would upvote as useful, and would then vote to close so that the Q&A helps act as a signpost to ask similar questions at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thank you. I do not think I have the reputation to close, but this can be closed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this information is readily available, but it is buried a little bit in the census's website. If this link is followed: https://www.census.gov/rdo/data/113th_congressional_and_2012_state_legislative_district_plans.html the data can be found. It is easy to miss, but can be found under the heading '113th Congress and 2012 State Legislative Block Equivalency Files.' I expected to find it under the relationship files heading.

Thank you to [BrenBarn](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/2013/brenbarn) over at the open data stack exchange, and this post for having the answer to this question:
https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6142/where-is-the-block-assignment-file-linking-2010-census-data-with-113th-congressi